# Check username already exist using mysqli and php (PhpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysqli

con.php

```
<?php
$_HOST="localhost";
$_USER="root";
$_PASS="";
$_DBNM="test";

$con=mysqli_connect($_HOST, $_USER, $_PASS, $_DBNM);

if ($con === false)
{
    die ("Database Connection Failed");
}
echo "Database Connection Succeed <br>";
?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
include("con.php");
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$level=$_POST['level'];

$sql = "select username from user where username='$username'";
$data = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0)
{   
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("Username Already Exist!");
        document.location:"register.html"</script>';
}
else
{
    $query = $con->query("INSERT INTO user (username, password, level) 
        VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$level')");
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("Registration Succeed!");
    document.location:"index.php"</script>';
}

?>
```

so the code is working for not inserting account if the username already exist, but it doesn't show the echo and it got stuck on the con.php.
Also, When I enter the non-exist username, the account added successfully but the echo didn't apppear.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript">` — Why are you using HTML 3.2 in 2019?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:phpmyadmin]? Your question isn't remotely about that particular GUI for accessing a database.

Comment: Your problem is caused by a typo (voting to close). Assignments are done with `=` not `:`. Run your JavaScript through a linter like https://jshint.com/

Comment: I can do the md5 password later. I'm using html for the form. I'm using XAMPP

Comment: @RyckK md5 is cracked use bcrypt pls

Comment: **Danger**: You are planning to use [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) — MD5 has been too weak for password hashing for years — and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: Please.. just answer on what i'm asking for

Comment: You don't have php errors you have JS syntax errors. Check your console

Comment: @RyckK — "Please.. just answer on what i'm asking for" — **Pay attention**: I already said: Your problem is caused by a typo (voting to close). Assignments are done with `=` not `:`. Run your JavaScript through a linter like jshint.com

Comment: Note that performing a SELECT to determine if a username is taken is not by itself sufficient to guarantee uniqueness in a multi-user system. You need to put a unique constraint on the username field, and then verify that the INSERT succeeded.

Comment: okay Quentin... My bad.. I actually didn't read it carefully.. Thankss dude

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to do a redirect you can use the header in php.

see example code.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){   
    header("location:register.html");
    exit();
}else{
    // do query...
   header("location:index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Also you should consider using prepare statements or moving to PDO
ref PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
ref header: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php